# PHP DateTime not converted to xsd:datetime

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, soapserver

I am experiencing this issue with a Soap Web Service I am creating. DateTime objects are not converted correctly and I end up with empty strings. I am using Zend Soap Server to build the service which is saving transactional data.

Is there a workaround to this issue besides converting it to a string? This seems to be a pretty fundamental problem with PHP's Soap implementation.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44383&edit=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to use a String to handle this.